# When can "to be" verb used in continuous tenses to mean "to behave in a particular way"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

Normally, we don't use continuous tenses with "**to be**" verb.

For example, we say "**she is beautiful**", not "**she is being beautiful**".

However, [the dictionary says](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/be)

> To be 6 [linking verb] to behave in a particular way
>
> He was just being rude.
>
> Don’t be silly.
>
> You’d better be careful.

So, when "**to be**" means "**to behave in a particular way**", we can use continuous tenses with it.

However, I don't know in which situations and with which adjectives we can use "**to be**" in continuous forms

For example, can we say?

-"**She is being silly/stubborn/friendly**"

-"**you are being naughty/bad/spoiled**" (talk to a boy)

If yes, then what is the difference between?

-"**She is being silly/stubborn/friendly**" vs "**She is silly/stubborn/friendly**"

-"**you are being naughty/bad/spoiled**" vs "**you are naughty/bad/spoiled**"

Answer (score 2):

> you are being naughty/bad/spoiled

This is saying that you are misbehaving. Making a choice to behave in a naughty/bad/spoiled way.

> you are naughty/bad/spoiled

This says that it's your nature to be naughty/bad/spoiled, not a chosen behavior.

In practice, of course the distinction is not necessarily obvious --- how can we know whether someone is choosing to behave badly or whether it is their unalterable nature to be that way?

Comment: Do we use it with positive adjectives like "friendly", "nice"... Is "*she is being nice /friendly...*" correct?

Comment: Yes, we can.  _She is friendly_ = she's a naturally friendly person. _She is being friendly_ = she is making a special effort to be kind or welcoming to someone on a particular occasion.